# A duality of finite groups coming from a surjective homomorphism with finite kernel of algebraic tori

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, abelian-groups

$\newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm Hom}}
\newcommand{\Gm}{{{\mathbb G}_{m,{\Bbb C}}}}
\newcommand{\X}{{\sf X}}
$ I am looking for a reference for the following lemma (for which I know a proof):

> **Lemma.**
> Let $\varphi\colon S\to T$ be a surjective homomorphism of algebraic $\Bbb C$-tori with finite kernel $A=\ker\varphi$.
> Write
> $$\X^*(A):=\Hom(A,\Gm)$$
> for the character group of $A$.
> Write $\X_*(T):=\Hom(\Gm\,,T)$ for the cocharacter group of $T$, and set
> $$M={\rm coker}\big[\varphi_*\colon \X_*(S)\to \X_*(T)\big].$$
> Then there is a canonical nondegenerate pairing of finite abelian groups
> $$\X^*(A)\times M\to {\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}.$$

Comment: What is the pairing, e.g., for the map of maximal tori coming from $\operatorname{SL}_n \to \operatorname{PGL}_n$?

Comment: @LSpice: $A=\mu_n$, ${\sf X}^*(A)={\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z}$, $M=\frac1n{\Bbb Z}/{\Bbb Z}$, $$\langle \chi, x\rangle =\chi\cdot x.$$

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathsf X^*(A), \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ is $A(\mathbb C)$ itself, right, *via* $a \mapsto \chi \mapsto \tfrac1{2\pi i}\log(\chi(a))$?  So we are looking for a nice map $M \to A(\mathbb C)$ (an isomorphism, I guess).

Comment: @LSpice: I want to do that over an arbitrary filed and get a pairing of Galois modules.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439619/a-duality-of-finite-groups-coming-from-a-surjective-homomorphism-with-finite-ker#comment1133934_439619), I would imagine that over a positive-characteristic field you would need at least to look at $\mathbb Z_{(p)}/\mathbb Z$, or maybe $\mu(k^\text{sep})$.  But, once you've done that, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathsf X^*(A), \mu(k^\text{sep}))$ is still $A(k^\text{sep})$, I think, and that group carries a perfectly good Galois action.  Of course this doesn't mean you *must* think this way, but maybe you *can*!

Comment: Is the map like this: choose $n$ that kills $M$.  Then $M \to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathsf X^*(A), \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ by sending $\mu \in M$ to $\chi \mapsto \frac1 n\langle\chi, \lambda\rangle$, where $\varphi_*(\lambda) = n\mu$ (thinking of $\mathsf X^*(A)$ as $\mathsf X^*(S)/\varphi^*\mathsf X^*(T)$)?

Comment: @LSpice: I regard $A$ as a finite commutative group scheme.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133939), meaning in particular that you don't want to pass to smooth subschemes, I guess, as I was implicitly [doing](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133935).  Right, that makes sense.  Did I get the right [map](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133938), after correcting for that issue?

Comment: @LSpice:  "Did I get the right map?" Yes, I think so.

Comment: @LSpice: "Did I get the right map?" Not exactly. If $A=\mu_2\times \mu_8$, you must take $n=8$, which will kill $\mu_2$. One should work with free abelian groups (the character and cocharacter groups of $S$ and $T$).

Comment: @LSpice: Exactly!

Comment: Oops, sorry, I deleted the comment to which you are [responding](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439619/a-duality-of-finite-groups-coming-from-a-surjective-homomorphism-with-finite-ker#comment1133944_439619) to make sure I was understanding [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439619/a-duality-of-finite-groups-coming-from-a-surjective-homomorphism-with-finite-ker#comment1133942_439619).  The comment was: then I guess the claim is that, if $L_1 \to L_2$ is a finite-index inclusion of integer lattices, then the Pontrjagin dual of $L_2/L_1$ is the quotient $L_1^*/L_2^*$ of dual lattices.

Comment: @LSpice: We embed ${\sf X}_*(T)$ into  ${\sf X}_*(S)\otimes {\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, I need this assertion about lattices.

Comment: I am not sure that [that](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133942) is a problem. $\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Your $A$ could arise from $\varphi : \GL_1 \times \GL_1 \to \GL_1 \times \GL_1$ given by $(z, w) \mapsto (z^2, w^8)$.  Then we could take $n = 8$, as you say.  If $\mu$ is $z \mapsto (z, 1)$, then $8\mu$ equals $\varphi_*(4\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is $z \mapsto (z, 1)$, so [my map](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1133940) sends (the image in $M$ of) $\mu$ to $\chi \mapsto \tfrac1 2\langle\chi, \lambda\rangle$. I think that might be OK.

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, your map is correct, I did not notice that you actually compute in lattices.