# Duality for finite quotient groups of finitely generated free abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, duality, abelian-groups

$\newcommand{\Z}{{\Bbb Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{{\Bbb Q}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm Hom}}
$ The following lemma is certainly known.

> **Lemma** (well-known).
> Let $B$ be a lattice (that is, a finitely generated free abelian group),
> and let $\iota\colon A\hookrightarrow B$ be a sublattice of finite index.
> Consider the dual lattices
> $$ A^\vee=\Hom(A,\Z),\quad\ B^\vee=\Hom(B,\Z),$$
> and the canonical injective homomorphism
> $\iota^\vee\colon B^\vee\hookrightarrow A^\vee$.
> Then there is a canonical perfect pairing of finite abelian groups
> $$A^\vee/B^\vee\times B/A\to \Q/\Z$$
> where we identify $B^\vee$ with $\iota^\vee(B^\vee)\subseteq A^\vee$
> and  $A$ with $\iota(A)\subseteq B$.
> In particular, $|A^\vee/B^\vee|=|B/A|$.

I am looking for a ***reference*** rather than a proof. I have a proof, see below.
The formula for the pairing was suggested
in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3622165/37763) and
in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439619/a-duality-of-finite-groups-coming-from-a-surjective-homomorphism-with-finite-ker#comment1133938_439619) of @LSpice.
I still hope to find a reference...

*Proof.*
Let $n\in \Z_{>0}$ be such that $nB\subseteq A$.
For $b\in B$, $\,a^\vee \in A^\vee$, write
$$[b]=b+A\in B/A,\qquad [a^\vee]=a^\vee+B^\vee\in A^\vee/B^\vee.$$
We set
$$ \big\langle [a^\vee], [b]\big\rangle =\frac1n \langle a^\vee, a\rangle+\Z\in\Q/\Z
\quad\ \text{where}\ \,a=nb\in A,\ \,n\in\Z_{>0}\,.$$
It is easy to see that this pairing is well defined
(does not depend on the choices of $n$ and of the representatives
$a^\vee$ of $[a^\vee]$ and $b$ of $[b]$).

It remains to show that our pairing is nondegenerate. Write $d={\rm rank}\, A= {\rm rank}\, B$.
By Lang, Algebra, 3rd Edition, Theorem III.7.8, there exists a basis $(e_i)$ of $B$ such that
$(n_i e_i)$ is a basis of $A$, where $i=1,\dots, d,\ \,n_i\in \Z_{>0}\,$.
Therefore, it suffices to consider the case $d=1$.

When $d=1$, we may assume that $A=\Z$, $B=\frac1n \Z$, $n\in\Z_{>0}\,$.
Then we may write  $A^\vee=\Z$, $B^\vee=n\Z$.
For $\,a^\vee\in A^\vee=\Z$, $\,b=\frac1n a\in B\subset\Q$, $\,a\in A=\Z$,
we have
$$ \big\langle [a^\vee],[b]\big\rangle= \big\langle [a^\vee],[\frac1n a]\big\rangle
       =\frac1n a^\vee\!\cdot a+\Z\in\Q/\Z.$$
If one of the classes $[a^\vee]\in A^\vee/B^\vee=\Z/n\Z$
and $[b]=[\frac1n a]\in B/A=\frac1n\Z/\Z$ is nonzero,
then one of the integers $a^\vee, a$ is not divisible by $n$,
and taking the other of these two integers to be 1,
we obtain that the product
$$\big\langle [a^\vee],[b]\big\rangle =
      \frac1n a^\vee\!\cdot a+\Z\neq 0\in\Q/\Z,$$
which completes the proof of the lemma.

Comment: Is there any specific to the ring $\mathbf{Z}$, or could the question be asked in the context of modules over PIDs?

Comment: @YCor: I don't know. The reference to Lang is about modules over PID.